# running ECSTask in IOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I am new to IOS platform. I have a code snippet written using JAVA API.

```
     AmazonECS amazonECS = new AmazonECSClient(credentials).withRegion(usWest1);           
     String command="bash /opt/run-task.sh "+"/mnt/s3/inputFile1::/mnt/s3/inputFile2"+" "+ "outputFile";

       ContainerOverride containerOverrides = new ContainerOverride().withCommand(command).withName("<<container name>>");
       TaskOverride overrides = new TaskOverride().withContainerOverrides(containerOverrides);
       RunTaskRequest runTaskRequest = new RunTaskRequest().withCluster("<<cluster name>>").withTaskDefinition("<<task definition arn>>")
               .withOverrides(overrides).withGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                    System.out.println(progressEvent.getBytesTransferred());
                    System.out.println(progressEvent.getEventType());
                }
            });


       Task task = new Task().withTaskDefinitionArn("<<task definition arn>>")
                        .withOverrides(overrides);

        RunTaskResult runTaskResult = amazonECS.runTask(runTaskRequest).withTasks(task);
        List<Failure> failures = runTaskResult.withTasks(task).getFailures();
```

I am using ffmpeg to merge few video files as single file. I need to know if there is equivalent functionality available in IOS.

Comment: if you asking for merging video files then follow below tutorials
https://abdulazeem.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/video-manipulation-in-ios-resizingmerging-and-overlapping-videos-in-ios/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: I am looking for invoking ECS Task in IOS. Merging file part is already completed and tested via Java API. thank you

Comment: We took an work around. exposed this as Java API and invoked it from iOS